# mocking 'pipe' in jasmine tests and TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I'm having a problem with tests. I'm getting error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined`

method in directive:

```
@HostListener('mouseenter')
  onMouseenter(): void {
    forkJoin([
      this.dateService.formatDate(dateStart).pipe(take(1)),
      this.dateService.formatDate(dateEnd).pipe(take(1))
    ]).subscribe((dates) => {
      this.showTooltip(`${dates[0]} - ${dates[1]}`);
    });
  }
```

(formatDate returns Observable string)

in test:

```
fit('should call mouse enter', () => {
    directive.onMouseenter();
    expect(directive.showTooltip).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

should i mock pipe somehow?
thanks!

Comment: What is `dateService.formatDate` returning?

Comment: it returns Observable<string>

Comment: It is clear `dateService.formatDate` is not returning what you expect. Have you set up a mock and a return value?

Comment: These users are right, you are most likely not mocking `dateService` correctly. If you provide your full test suite code, I can help you mock it.

Comment: i posted how test looks

Answer (score -2):

test looks like this

```
fdescribe('TooltipDirective', () => {
  let directive: TooltipDirective;
  let mockDateService: jasmine.SpyObj<DateService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockDateService = jasmine.createSpyObj('dateService', ['formatDate']);
    directive = new TooltipDirective(null, null, mockDateService);
    directive.tooltipData = {dateStart: new Date(), endDate: Date()};

    spyOn(directive, 'showTooltip');
  });

  fit('should show tooltip', () => {
    directive.onMouseenter();
    expect(directive.showTooltip).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```